# string produced by pythons json.dumps() errors when loading with javascripts JSON.parse() at escaped double quotes

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have the following string with two escaped doublequotes:

```
var morgen = '{"a": [{"title": "Fotoausstellung \"Berlin, Berlin\""]}';
```

This is valid JSON as far as I know. Still, executing `JSON.parse(morgen)` fails with

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object at line 1 column 36 of the JSON data
```

The string was produced by pythons `json.dumps()` method.

Comment: Apart from the backslash issue, that isn't valid JSON: it's missing a `}` on the inner object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pointy mentions, you *should* be able to just embed that JSON as an object in your JavaScript source, rather than as a string which has to be parsed.

However, to print that JSON with escape codes suitable for use as a JavaScript string you can tell Python to encode it with the 'unicode-literal' codec. However, that will produce a `bytes` object, so you need to decode it to make a text string. You can use the 'ASCII' codec for that. Eg,

```
import json

# The problem JSON using Python's raw string syntax
s = r'{"a": [{"title": "Fotoausstellung \"Berlin, Berlin\""}]}'

# Convert the JSON string to a Python object
d = json.loads(s)
print(d)

# Convert back to JSON, with escape codes.
json_bytes = json.dumps(d).encode('unicode-escape')
print(json_bytes)

# Convert the bytes to text
print(json_bytes.decode('ascii'))
```

**output**

```
{'a': [{'title': 'Fotoausstellung "Berlin, Berlin"'}]}
b'{"a": [{"title": "Fotoausstellung \\\\"Berlin, Berlin\\\\""}]}'
{"a": [{"title": "Fotoausstellung \\"Berlin, Berlin\\""}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to double the backslash characters:

```
var morgen = '{"a": [{"title": "Fotoausstellung \\"Berlin, Berlin\\""]}';
```

That is necessary because JavaScript will remove the single backslashes when it parses the overall string constant. (The `\"` pair in a string constant is interpreted as meaning a single `"` character.)

If all you want is that structure as a JavaScript object, you'd just do this:

```
var morgen = {"a": [{"title": "Fotoausstellung \"Berlin, Berlin\""]};
```

Comment: I had it narrowed down to that part of the json. The whole thing is dynamically generated and much bigger. So how many levels of escaping do I need? In what cases does javascript un-escape?

Comment: You haven't posted the Python code that dumps out the content. If your Python code is building JavaScript, just drop the JSON directly into the code: JSON syntax is a subset of JavaScript object literal syntax; it basically *is* JavaScript code. Thus it can be used directly.

Comment: well the python code is `json.dumps(my_dict)`. But I put the result in single quotes. I will just remove them and hope it works